# Calling Zapier trigger from Django Code

Tags: django, python-3.x, automation, zapier, zapier-cli

Is there any way I can call the "**Zapier trigger**" from my Django Code,

Basically, I am having a Django form where the user will enter several email-id and when the user clicks on send button then I want to send this form data to Zapier in order to do the next **action** like writing in **google spreadsheet** or **sending email** to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. The easiest way to do this is to have the form submit against your server and use a library like `requests` to POST to Zapier. This way, you don't have to worry about CORS or revealing the hook url to your users.

Hope that makes sense. ​Let me know if you've got any other questions!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure from your question if this is related to how to make the call from Python (which [@xavdid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1825390/xavdid) answered) or how to trigger a zap. If this is about triggering a Zap, here's the answer.

[Setup a Zap](https://zapier.com/help/zap-creation/) by choosing the [Webhooks by Zapier](https://zapier.com/help/webhooks/) app as the trigger. Choose catch a raw hook, if you need more control. In the next step, you will receive a URL where you can POST your form-data.

Everytime you POST data the Zap will be triggered. You can use the data available from your request in the action step for Google Sheets or Emails.

Here are a few Zap Templates that you could start from.

- [Add info to Google Sheets from a Webhook POST](https://zapier.com/app/editor/template/1035)
- [Send emails from a Webhook POST](https://zapier.com/app/editor/template/62) (Using Zapier's email app)
- [Send emails from a Webhook POST](https://zapier.com/app/editor/template/1755) (using Gmail)